# Is there a "not equal" in a linq join

Tags: linq, join, equals

I am trying accomplish the LINQ query below but I need a "not equal" instead of equal, so that filteredEmployees has all employees from groupA minus groupB.

```
List<Employee> groupA = getEmployeeA();
List<Employee> groupB = getEmployeeB();        

var filteredEmployees = from a in groupA 
                        join b in groupB on a.Name equals b.Name
                        select a;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linq not equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669507/using-linq-not-equals)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You don't need a join for that:

```
var filteredEmployees = groupA.Except(groupB);
```

Note that this will be a sequence of unique employees - so if there are any duplicates in `groupA`, they will only appear once in `filteredEmployees`. Of course, it also assumes you've got a reasonable equality comparer<sup>1</sup>. If you need to go specifically on name, you can use [`ExceptBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq):

```
var filteredEmployees = groupA.ExceptBy(groupB, employee => employee.Name);
```

Or without going into a third party library:

```
var groupBNames = new HashSet<string>(groupB.Select(x => x.Name));
var filteredEmployees = groupA.Where(x => !groupBNames.Contains(x.Name));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out in the comments, you can pass in an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as an argument to `Except`. I have a `ProjectionEqualityComparer` class in [MiscUtil](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil) which makes it easy to build a comparer of the kind you need:

```
// I can't remember the exact method name, but it's like this :)
var comparer = ProjectionEqualityComparer<Employee>.Create(x => x.Name);
var filteredEmployees = groupA.Except(groupB, comparer);
```

Comment: Note to @Robert: You can provide an `IEqualityComparer<Employee>` implementation for an overload of `Except`. Useful if overriding Equals/GetHashCode is either (a) impossible or (b) undesirable.

Comment: Thanks. The 3rd option you wrote did the trick. I tried the IEqualityComparer before and it did not work.

Comment: I love the hashset method without the 3rd party. It's pretty slick.

Comment: there might be need to go for join
say i have two tables employee and department and i want to left join employee with department by primary key of department but there is a constrain that department and employee both have column expense and i want result(AND operation in  join) that employee expense not equal to department expense

Comment: @VISHMAY: That's a long way beyond what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 5):

No, a "not equal" operator would get you all combinations of groupA and groupB except the ones where the items were the same.

Using the Except method gets you what you want:

```
var filteredEmployees = groupA.Except(groupB);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Entity Framework 6, I've gotten better results using

```
var filteredEmployees = groupA.Where(a => !groupB.Select(b => b.Name).Contains(a.Name));
```