# Filter From the Two Data Table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Having two data tables called dtSource and dtDest. From these two data table have to filter the rows which are all have the Mismatched values in first column(PRIMARY).

This is what I have done:

```
var valueMismatchInBoth = from c in dtSource.AsEnumerable() 
                          where (from o in dtDest.AsEnumerable() 
                                 select o["PRIMARY"]).Contains(c["PRIMARY"].ToString()) 
                          select c;
```

Comment: please share what you have done till now.

Comment: var valueMismatchInBoth = from c in dtSource.AsEnumerable()
                                                          where (from o in dtDest.AsEnumerable() select o["PRIMARY"]).Contains(c["PRIMARY"].ToString())
                                                          select c;

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helps

```
var valuematchInBoth = from c in dtSource.AsEnumerable()
                          join o in dtDest.AsEnumerable()
                          on o["PRIMARY"] equals c["PRIMARY"]
                          select c;

var valueMismatchInBoth = dtSource.Except(valuematchInBoth);
```

another solution is

```
var valueMismatchInBoth = from c in dtSource.AsEnumerable()
                          from o in dtDest.AsEnumerable()
                          where o["PRIMARY"] != c["PRIMARY"]
                          select c;
```

Comment: But I want to get mismatched rows. the above query gave the matched row as a result.

Comment: have a look at this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762869/is-there-a-not-equal-in-a-linq-join