# Self JOIN linq with not equal

Tags: c#, linq

myTuples has `{string id, int start, int end}`

With this sample data:

```
{A, 10, 11}, 
{B, 20, 30}, 
{C, 25, 35}, 
{D, 25, 28}, 
{E,  7, 35},
```

The result should be: `x1 < x2 < x3 < x4`

```
{7,  10, 11, 35} -- row id=A {10, 11} between id=E {7,35}
{7,  25, 28, 35} -- row id=D {25, 28} between id=E {7,35}
{20, 25, 28, 30} -- row id=D {25, 28} between id=B {20,30}
```

If you add  `{F, 15, 40}` then `row=B` can be in the inside too.

```
{15, 20, 30, 40} -- row id=B {20, 30} between id=F {15,40}
```

This is what I have try.

```
var query = from t1 in myTuples
            join t2 in myTuples
                 on t1.id equals t2.id
            where (t1.start > t2.start && t1.end < t2.end)
               || (t1.start < t2.start && t1.end > t2.end)
            select new
            {
                x1 = t1.start,
                x2 = t2.start,
                x3 = t1.end, 
                x4 = t2.end
            };
```

But my first problem is there isnt `not equal` join.

The last part doesnt matter much I can fix it later. But Im thinking something like

```
 select new
 {
   x1 = t1.start < t2.start : t1.start : t2.start,
   x2 = t1.start < t2.start : t2.start : t1.start,
   x3 = t1.end < t2.en: t1.end: t2.end,
   x4 = t1.end < t2.en: t2.end: t1.end
 };
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762869/is-there-a-not-equal-in-a-linq-join

Comment: @MauriceReeves Not sure if duplicate, because in that case he want `groupA MINUS  groupB` I want `groupA CROSS JOIN groupA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having defined

```
 var myTuples = new Tuple<string,int,int>[5] {
new Tuple<string,int,int>("A",10,11), new Tuple<string,int,int>("B",20,30),
new Tuple<string,int,int>("C",25,35), new Tuple<string,int,int>("D",25,28),
new Tuple<string,int,int>("E",7,35) };
```

I can do a self join with not equal using SelectMany.

```
     var selfJoinNotEqual = myTuples
.SelectMany( x => myTuples.Where(y => y.Item1 != x.Item1).Select( y => new { x, y}));
```

For the second part, add another select

```
.Select(z => new {  
    x1 = ( z.x.Item2 <= z.y.Item2 ? z.x.Item2 : z.y.Item2),
    x2 = (z.x.Item2 <= z.y.Item2 ? z.y.Item2 : z.x.Item2) ,
    x3 = (z.x.Item3 <= z.y.Item3 ? z.x.Item3 : z.y.Item3),
    x4 = (z.x.Item3 <= z.y.Item3 ? z.y.Item3 : z.x.Item3) 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Any idea on if my query is equivalent to yours?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks

Comment: on your query what is `Item1` ?? some default name because you didnt name the properties?

Comment: It's your id, the first item of the Tuple, Item2 is start and Item3 is end. I used the default values

Answer (score 0):

After comment on Maurice, realize I search for the wrong question. Im doing `CROSS JOIN` not `INNER JOIN`

```
var combo = from t1 in myTuples
            from t2 in myTuples
            where
               t1.id < t2.id
            select new { t1, t2 };
```