# using equal and not equal in a linq join

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to convert following SQL query to linq;

```
select Or.Amount, Usr.Name, Usr.Email
from [order] as Or
left join vw_AllUsers as Usr on Usr.UserId = Or.UserId and Usr.RoleName <> 'Admin'
```

I couldn't find a way to use **equal** and **not equal** in the same join..
If **Usr.RoleName <> 'Admin'** was **Usr.RoleName = 'Admin'**, the linq statement could be written like that

```
var result =  from Or in context.orders
              join Usr in context.vw_AllUsers on 
              new { userid = Or.UserId, role = "Admin"}
              equals
              new { userid = Usr.UserId, role = Usr.RoleName}
              select ........
```

or i can handle it in where part of the linq to get same result, as follows

```
where !Usr.RoleName.Equals("Admin")
```

but is it possible to handle this in join part of the linq ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linq not equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669507/using-linq-not-equals)

Comment: @nawfal not a duplicate, this question is about using both equal and not equal in the same query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LINQ only supports equality joins, there's not a way to use a different operator in the `join` itself.

As you point out, you can just use a `where` statement for the same effect.  If you didn't have an equality comparison to join on, you can use multiple `from` clauses.

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause):

> The `equals` operator
>
> ---

A `join` clause performs an equijoin. In other words, you can only base matches on the equality of two keys. Other types of comparisons such as "greater than" or "not equals" are not supported. To make clear that all joins are equijoins, the `join` clause uses the `equals` keyword instead of the == operator. The `equals` keyword can only be used in a `join` clause and it differs from the == operator in one important way. With `equals`, the left key consumes the outer source sequence, and the right key consumes the inner source. The outer source is only in scope on the left side of `equals` and the inner source sequence is only in scope on the right side.

> Non-Equijoins
>
> ---

You can perform non-equijoins, cross joins, and other custom join operations by using multiple `from` clauses to introduce new sequences independently into a query. For more information, see [How to: Perform Custom Join Operations (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations).

Answer (score 14):

Not equal join could be achieved like,

```
var result =  from Or in context.orders
          join Usr in context.vw_AllUsers on 
          new { userid = Or.UserId, IsNotAnAdmin = true}
          equals
          new { userid = Usr.UserId, IsNotAnAdmin = (Usr.RoleName != "Admin") }
          select ........
```

The sql equivalent for the above linq will have a case statement in the join condition.

Comment: What a kludge, but, love the creativity.  Seems like EF should have simple stuff like this built in.

Comment: i'm a little late, but check my answer

Answer (score 0):

use [DefaultIfEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty)

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the type parameter's
> default value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

So you can do the following:

```
var result =
    from Or in context.orders
    from Usr in context.vw_AllUsers.Where(Usr => Usr.UserId == Or.UserId && Usr.RoleName != "Admin").DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
    select new { Or.Amount, Usr };
```

*(I'm selecting the whole `Usr` object instead of its fields, because it can be `null`.)*

But keep in mind that not all types have the default value `null`. `DefaultIfEmpty()` on an empty `List<int>` for example results in a list containing the element 0. In that case, you could first convert it to a nullable int list `List<int?>`.