# LINQ join with multiple conditions of different kind

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to translate following T-SQL query into LINQ:

```
SELECT  * FROM  table_A JOIN table_B ON table_A.key = table_B.key AND
                                table_A.Trouble <> table_B.Trouble
```

Stackoverflow is full with similar questions, but in my case there are two conditions but each of them has different operator ("equals to" and "not equals to"). Is there any way to get the same result using LINQ?

Comment: Linq to SQL / LINQ to entities ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642421/using-equal-and-not-equal-in-a-linq-join

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `join` syntax, you have to use a `where` clause to connect the two

```
var query = from a in table_A
            from b in table_B
            where a.key = b.key &&
                  a.Trouble != b.Trouble
            select new { a, b };
```

Comment: I think it doesn't compile in C#  `<>` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this query. It should be work fast

```
var query = from a in table_A
            from b in table_B.where(x=>x.key==a.key && x.Trouble != a.Trouble)
            select new { a, b };
```