# Not Equal two Generic Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have two generic lists.  They have mostly different fields, but there are 4 fields they have in common.  I want to get the list of items that are in one of the lists but not the other using those four fields as the definition of "equality".

Here was my attempt at solving the problem.

```
var unMatchedData = from liveLines in liveList
    join oldList in comapreSnapshotList
    on new {liveLines.ClientNo, liveLines.SequenceNo, liveLines.LineNo, liveLines.Text} equals
    new {oldList.ClientNo, oldList.SequenceNo, oldList.LineNo, oldList.Text}
    select new KNOWTXTS
    {
        ClientNo = liveLines.ClientNo,
        SequenceNo = liveLines.SequenceNo,
        LineNo = liveLines.LineNo,
        Text = liveLines.Text
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669507/using-linq-not-equals

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762869/is-there-a-not-equal-in-a-linq-join

Comment: _"find items that do not match in either list"_ Do you want to find items that are in `liveList` but not in `comapreSnapshotList` and the other way around?

Comment: Or do you want the inverse of a join operaton?  That is the cross product that filters out all items that do not have the same key (as opposed to a join, which is the cross product filtered by all items that do have the same key).

Comment: Yes, i need to find items that are not in either.

Comment: @DavidJohnson That's not clear at all.  You have been asked which of several options you wanted, you then said 'Yes' (it's not a yes/no question) followed by an entirely ambiguous statement.

Comment: @DavidJohnson: Maybe i understand something wrong, but you want to find all items of both lists that are not in one of both lists? Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Sorry- I think there is some misunderstanding. The old list contains a list of old data, i need to find, based on the fields I am joining above the items that are no longer on the new list, and also items that have been added to the new list since the generation of the old list.

Comment: @DavidJohnson That has nothing to do with a join operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to find the set difference.

```
var newElements = liveList.Select(l => new {
                      l.ClientNo, l.SequenceNo, l.LineNo, l.Text
                  });
var oldElements = comapreSnapshotList.Select(l => new {
                      l.ClientNo, l.SequenceNo, l.LineNo, l.Text
                  });
var newElementsInNew = newElements.Except(oldElements);
var deletedFromNew   = oldElements.Except(newElements);


// if you need the original object in the list 
var newElements = from obj in liveList 
                  join newEle in newElementsInNew 
                  on new {obj.ClientNo, obj.SequenceNo, obj.LineNo, obj.Text} equals newEle
                  select obj;
var deletedElements = from obj in comapreSnapshotList
                  join deletedEle in deletedFromNew   
                  on new {obj.ClientNo, obj.SequenceNo, obj.LineNo, obj.Text} equals deletedEle
                  select obj;
```

Comment: Take a look at the answers in the proposed duplicates.  If you need the actual items and not the anonymous type used for the comparison then they'll be better.