# How to rewrite this LINQ query with SQL syntax and <>?

Tags: c#, linq

The following query joins two tables on serverID and returns the ServerID's and components belonging to them as shown below

**LINQ**

```
var header  = from a in this.db.Servers
               where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
               join b in this.db.Components
               on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID into g
               select new
               {
               a.ServerID,                                
               Comp = g.Select(x => x.Name),                              
               };
```

**Output**

```
Server X
common component
component 1x
component 2x
component 3x
Server Y
common component
component 1y
component 2y
component 3y
Server Z
common component
component 1z
component 2z
component 3z
```

how to retrieve the above result , removing record **the common component** ? This can be achieved in SQL using <> not equal to. how it can be achieved with the above code ?

Comment: So you just want to exclude the `common component` from the result set?

Comment: @demo_user check [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3762875/1671639), you wll surely get idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linq not equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669507/using-linq-not-equals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a constraint on component:

```
select new
{
   a.ServerID,                                
   Comp = g.Where(x => x.Name != "common component").Select(x => x.Name),                              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `select` projection, just filter it out:

```
Comp = g.Where(x => x.Name != "common component").Select(x => x.Name),
```